# JavaScript: The Good Parts regexp.exec(String) explanation

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to understand what is happening in this code example from Crockford's JavaScript:The Good Parts.

```
// Break a simple html text into tags and texts.
// (See string.replace for the entityify method.)
// For each tag or text, produce an array containing
// [0] The full matched tag or text
// [1] The tag name
// [2] The /, if there is one
// [3] The attributes, if any
var text = '<html><body bgcolor=linen><p>' +
'This is <b>bold<\/b>!<\/p><\/body><\/html>';
var tags = /[^<>]+|<(\/?)([A-Za-z]+)([^<>]*)>/g;
var a, i;
while ((a = tags.exec(text))) {

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    document.writeln(('// [' + i + '] ' + a[i]).entityify( ));
        }
    document.writeln( );
    }
```

The hardest part to understand how the "g" global is affecting the way the regex is interpreted. I don't understand the regex either. A line by line explanation would be great.

Comment: when g is selected you call exec many times to get the next match, but when its not it always returns the first match. Im not sure what you're asking exactly though.

Comment: Alright I understand the g part now

Comment: OK I created a jsbin that should help a little. http://jsbin.com/jusesi/3/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice diagram of your regex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
[^<>]+     One or more characters that is not < or > (no tags found)

|          or

<          Less than sign
(\/?)      slash (/), optional
([A-Za-z]+) One or more English letters
([^<>]*)   Zero or more non < or > charaters
>          Greater than sign
```

`(....)` means it is a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). They are used so that you can extract parts of the tags.

The `g` flag means you can repeatedly execute `.exec` to get many results. Without the `g` flag your `while` will go in an infinite loop. (Basically it's a step-by-step `.match`.)

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the `exec` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property.
>
> <sub>Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec</sub>

---

For the code itself, the `for` loop will print the matched text of your capture groups. For example:

```
// [0] </b>         <-- Matched text (whole tag)
// [1] /            <-- Capture group 1, used to capture the slash (closing tag)
// [2] b            <-- Capture group 2, used to capture tag name
// [3]              <-- Capture group 3, used to capture attributes (if any)
```

Comment: Can you explain the rail diagram?

Comment: why is there none of < >  before > on the bottom rail. Also, what does the question mark mean in (\/?)

Comment: @TheBear - Added explanation.

Comment: @TheBear - `[^<>]*` means `none of < >` and `?` means optional (at most one).

Answer (score 2):

`/` - Start the regular expression pattern

`[^<>]+` - one or more characters which are not angle brackets (this includes newline characters)

`|` - or

`<` - left angle bracket

`(\/)?` - an optional `/` (this is capture group 1)

`([A-Za-z]+)` - one or more alpha characters (this is capture group 2)

`([^<>]*)` - 0 or more characters which are not angle brackets (this includes newline characters) (this is capture group 3)

`>` - right angle bracket

`/g` - end the regular expression pattern and set the global modifier which will continue matching until the end of input.

Of note: The sample above indicates a reversal of groups 1 and 2 in the comments.

As mentioned by drjimmie1976, regex101 is a great resource:  [example of this regex](http://regex101.com/r/bU0tZ7).

Answer (score 2):

The global flag doesn't affect how the regular expression is interpreted, but it affects how it is executed. Without the global flag the `exec` method would just find the first match and say that there was nothing more when you call it again, instead of returning a new match for each call until it has found all matches.

The regular expression:

`[^<>]` matches any character that is not `<` or `>`
`+` is a quantifier that means to do the previous match one or more times
`|` is the `or` operator
`<` matches the character `<`
`(...)` is used to capture a value
`\/?` matches the character `/`, `?` is a quantifier that means zero or one times
`[A-Za-z]+` matches any letter, one or more times
`[^<>]*` matches any character that is not `<` or `>`, zero or more times
`>` matches the character `>`

So, the part before `|` matches text in the code that is not HTML tags, and the part after matches one HTML tag, capturing the optional `/`, the tag name, and all attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The /g switch just means that it will keep searching for matches after the first one is found. Without it, the regexp stops after the first match.

As far as the regex itself goes, I'm not sufficiently expert to comment. But http://regex101.com/ is great - check the Quick Reference at bottom right of the page, enter your own, and start to get to grips with them.